# java.net.UnknownHostException: Name or service not known

Tags: java, docker

My docker-compose file:

```
webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    hostname: webservice-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ServerDockerfile // ServerDockerfile starts tomcat
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

webservices_test_client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TestsDockerfile
    depends_on:
      - webapp
```

When I try to send request to "http://webservice-server:8080/" via Apache HttpClient from tests in container webservices_test_client I am getting UnknownHostException.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://webservice-server:8080/");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

What's wrong? Thanks for answers.

Comment: is your port open for incoming connections?

Comment: @JAMSHAID yes, port is open

Comment: Is what you show here wrapped in a `services:` block, or is this the entire `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @DavidMaze it's entire docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file is missing a `version:` line and a `services:` wrapper.  This makes it an obsolete [version 1 Compose file](https://web.archive.org/web/20210302145052/https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/) that doesn't set up Docker networking for you.  Very current tools will have trouble running it because they'll interpret the file as the fourth-generation [Compose specification](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md).

At the top level, add a `version:` declaring what version to use (I tend to use the most recent non-"specification" version 3.8) and wrapping the declarations you have now in `services:`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ServerDockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  webservices_test_client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TestsDockerfile
    depends_on:
      - webapp
```

You do not need to declare `networks:`, `container_name:`, or `hostname:`.  In a version 2 or 3 Compose file, Compose sets these things up for you, and the Compose service names like `webapp` will be usable as host names to call between containers.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has further details.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specify the network. With `hostname: webservice-server` you just setting the host name inside the `webapp` container. You should have a network so that diffrent container could see each other. If you don't want to create network for each container, just use `networks: default aliases`

Comment: Please, can you explain me? I know, that docker-compose sets up a network for app by default. Containers auto connected to this network. If I am right, my question is as follows: “Why we need explicit create a network, if we have network that was created by default?” Thanks

Comment: @Michael because This feature is for later versions of docker-compose. In the version, you are using(V1), you need to specify the network.